# Retrofit JSON deserializing object's $ref reference to its original copy

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Microsoft.Net with Breeze for APIs and the results I get using Retrofit have nested repeated same objects. For example EmployeeJob has Customer navigation property so the APIs result looks like this

```
 {
   Id:1,
   "Customer_Id": 39,
    "Customer": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$type": "Wit.Trade.Entities.Customer, Wit.Trade",
        "CourtesyTitle": "Mr",
        "FirstName": "Ahmad"
    }
}
{
  Id:2
  "Customer_Id": 39,
    "Customer": {
        "$ref": "2" //here same customer Ahmad
    },
}
```

Now the Java `List` I get of these `EmployeeJobs` has only `Customer` in the first record and others have nothing. How can I map the `$ref:"2"` to its original value instead of this `$ref`.

**I don't want my server APIs to send the complete objects for network and performance reasons, that's why I want to deserialize these `$refs` on client side just like `Angularjs $resource service` does for us.**

Comment: Have you found a answer to this question by any chance?

Comment: I am doing it manually posting in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have worked arround manually for the $ref solution like this

```
//========== $ref manual solution for employee jobs' customers
            List<Customer> completedCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EmployeeJob empJob : empJobs) {
                if (empJob.Customer != null && empJob.Customer.Id == null && empJob .Customer.$ref != null) {
                    for (Customer comCus : completedCustomers) {
                        if (comCus.$id.equalsIgnoreCase(empJob.Customer.$ref))
                            empJob.Customer = comCus;
                    }
                } else
                    completedCustomers.add(empJob.Customer);
            }
```

Now `empJobs` has the $refs replaced with their corresponding Customers.

Comment: Jesse Wilson's reaction to your question on https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/146 was the suggestion to write an adapter like the GraphAdapterBuilder for Gson. Didn't you manage to do it? I can't confirm that it is "straightforward" like he said. I only partially understand it and that's not enough.