# I can't implement a custom getter on realm result because `this(realmObject).propertyName` is null always yet data is there

Tags: java, android, realm

When I fetch records from my web API it adds reference of the repeated and nested object instances like this.

```
[{
 Id:1,
 "Customer_Id": 39,
 "Customer": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$type": "Entities.Customer, Wit.Trade",
    "CourtesyTitle": "Mr",
    "FirstName": "Ahmad"
  }
},
{
 Id:2,
 "Customer_Id": 39,
 "Customer": {
    "$ref": "2" //here same customer Ahmad
  }
}]
```

Now when I fetch the records as RealmResults I want to check these references and replace them with non null/ non $ref real data objects from their corresponding table. Hence I implemented this custom `getter`.

```
//MiscStorage.java
public static Customer getCustomer(int customer_id) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return realm.where(Customer.class).equalTo("Id", customer_id).findFirst();
}

//Project.java which has a customer
public class Project extends RealmObject {
   public boolean isModified;
   public int $ref;
   public int $id;
   public int Customer_Id;
   public Customer Customer;
   public Customer getCustomer() {
     if (this.Customer== null || this.Customer.$id != 0)
         return MiscStorage.getCustomer(this.Customer_Id);
     else return Customer;
    }
}

//Customer.java
public class Customer extends RealmObject {
   public int $ref;
   public int $id;
   @PrimaryKey
   public int Id;
   public String Name;
}
```

**Problem:**
In my customer getter the `If` condition never hits because `this.Customer==null` is not true nor the `this.Customer.$id` gets its real value hence its always 0. **This $id not getting the real value is actually the core problem**. But actually without debug mode this is not null and also the `toString()` method contains value for `$id`. I do get the data in UI but the getter always gives null and when I debug it also gives me null.

Comment: Very colourful code!! For the `$id = 0` problem, please take a look at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging

Comment: But the problem is not debugging. Problem is this.Customer.$id actually has no value when accessed from within the class using `this`.

Comment: What is your Realm version? Is it 0.88.0+, or older than that?

Comment: Realm version is 0.88.3

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Is it possible to share the full source code of `getCustomer`'s object and `Customer`? BTW, `this.Customer` i guess this won't compile because of the `C`?

Comment: I have updated the code. `this.[Everything].[EveryProp]`'s value is null for me and not for = operator, not only Customer. I have to use this logic in many entities. This hack is due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771483/retrofit-json-deserializing-objects-ref-reference-to-its-original-copy

Comment: I made a project and did some testing again, and still cannot reproduce the issue. "But the problem is not debugging. " Are you sure? You might see `this.Customer = null` in the debugger window which actually is not true -- it is what we documented in https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do another testing debugging and report back.